# How to use this confing function

Tags: arduino-uno, library, functions

For INA3221 current sensor, I found this [library](https://github.com/switchdoclabs/SDL_Arduino_INA3221), however, I don't understand how to use the `INA3221SetConfig()` function as defined in the .cpp file [link](https://github.com/switchdoclabs/SDL_Arduino_INA3221/blob/master/SDL_Arduino_INA3221.cpp).

```
void SDL_Arduino_INA3221::INA3221SetConfig(void)
{

      // Set Config register to take into account the settings above
      uint16_t config =
          INA3221_CONFIG_ENABLE_CHAN1 |
          // INA3221_CONFIG_ENABLE_CHAN2 |
          // INA3221_CONFIG_ENABLE_CHAN3 |
          INA3221_CONFIG_RESET |
          INA3221_CONFIG_AVG1 |
          INA3221_CONFIG_VBUS_CT2 |
          INA3221_CONFIG_VSH_CT2 |
          INA3221_CONFIG_MODE_2 |
          INA3221_CONFIG_MODE_1 |
          INA3221_CONFIG_MODE_0;
      wireWriteRegister(INA3221_REG_CONFIG, config);
    }
```

It seems like the function is called automatically when the `.begin()` function is called and whatever is defined in the config function is written to the register. The use of | operator confuses me. I tried to comment out the some settings to see if it works but it makes no difference. There isn't any documentation so I am in a fix. Could you please tell how can I change the configuration settings e.g. instead of all the three channels or change the config_mode?

Comment: this is not an arduino related question ... it is a general programming question that may be a better fit at https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at the library, you can check yourself if this method (`INA3221SetConfig`) is called from the `begin` method (of the same class). Just trace back the methods manually until you find a call to this method.

About the `|` or 'bit-wise-or' operator (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C), these are used to set bits in a byte/word/long.

Most registers have 8, 16 or 32 bits and with the `|` operator you can easily set multiple bits at the same time. Each value (e.g. `INA3221_CONFIG_ENABLE_CHAN`) has a value that is a power of 2 (mostly defined in the form `1 << ..something..` you can add them (with +) or `|` them together, but | is more clear what the purpose is and repeatedly calling `|` the same bit twice is not a problem (it still gives the same result).

Comment: I had to learn about bit -wise operations and manipulations and it becomes understandable :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with your project